# Excel ProperCase to words

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a quick way (or any way for that matter) to convert proper case text to individual words. I have few thousand lines of rows and thought asking SO is better than splitting the text manually. Google couldnt help

for e.g. ""EffectiveFromDate should be translated to "Effective From Date"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this UDF:

```
Function ProperCaseToWords(x As String) As String
    Dim i As Byte
    'A=65, Z=90
    For i = 65 To 90
        x = Replace(x, Chr(i), " " & Chr(i))
    Next i
    ProperCaseToWords = Trim(x)
End Function
```

and then call it in any cell: `=ProperCaseToWords(A1)`

[image]

or call it from `Sub`:

```
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("A1:A100")
    cell.Value = ProperCaseToWords(cell.Value)
Next
```

Comment: Sleek, and it works as it should / thank you. much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
Sub SplitProper()

Dim rgLoop As Range, lCharLoop As Long, lChar As Long, sTemp As String

'turn off updates to speed up code execution
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

For Each rgLoop In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 2).Cells

    sTemp = rgLoop.Value
    For lCharLoop = Len(rgLoop.Value) To 2 Step -1

        lChar = Asc(Mid(sTemp, lCharLoop, 1))

        If lChar >= 65 And lChar <= 90 Then
            sTemp = Left(sTemp, lCharLoop - 1) & " " & Mid(sTemp, lCharLoop)
        End If

    Next

    rgLoop.Value = sTemp


Next rgLoop

'turn off updates to speed up code execution
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With


End Sub
```